# how to convert xls to csv using IOS library?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, excel, csv

I need to read xls files in my IOS app. First of all, I want to convert xls files to csv format files, then my app parse csv files, but I can't find any ios library to convert xls to csv, please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .xls file, you can use the open source [DHlibxls](https://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls) library to read the file into your app. This is an ObjectiveC framework that wraps a C-based library. The library is quite mature.

Answer (score 0):

ios or any objecive-framework doesn't provide any thing for accesseing Microsoft's xls :(

To convert-xls to/fro csv is itself a project in it!!!

On top of this, there are different format of xls, now xlsx files. And writing a xls and reading it back in proper way is tooooo-cumbursome task to accomplish. However we have managed to read it but it is not 100% efficient :(

I guess in near future you may want to move to xlsx file then your task will be a lot more difficult. You can check yourself, change the file name extension to .zip and unzip you will see many files, one having row numbers, another columns, third with links, fourth with contents and so on. Mapping and getting in correct form in not impossible but needs a lot of work.

There can be many other ways to do, I can suggest to use java api to do, or even save you xls to csv directory from excel, then your work will be easy.